# Can we Use "FILE" in C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, pointers

In C Programming, while using file concept, we using FILE keyword for declare a file pointer. like

FILE *f1;

Now my doubt is, can we use this FILE pointer in C++?

Comment: Yes you can, but you shouldn't. Googling "c++ file input" would have given you a good answer.

Comment: "keyword" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Downvoters… this isn't a political litmus test. The question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Downvote tooltip: "this question does not show any research effort"...

Answer (score 5):

`FILE *` is part of the C standard library, and C++ includes the entire C library. So, `FILE *` code will continue to work.

However, C++ offers more safety and convenience with its own `<iostream>` library. For example, the file is closed and flushed for you automatically when its handle is destroyed, which in turn happens if some exception is causing the I/O function to exit.

Use [`std::fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) for formatted text I/O or [`std::filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) for higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but it is not recommended - use [C++ streams](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html) instead

Comment: `fopen("can_of_worms", "r+")`...